# chart stream not rendering correctly

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My controller, in a nutshell is this:

```
        chart1.SeriesCollection.Add(SC);
        using (MemoryStream ms = chart1.GetChartStream())
        {
            return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
        }
```

My view is this:

```
        $('#targetDiv').load("Home/GetImage");
```

And I'm getting garbled characters when rendered. Any ideas?

thanks,
rodchar

Comment: thanks all for the help, rod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an `img` tag:

```
<img src="Home/GetImage" alt="" />
```

When you write `$('#targetDiv').load("Home/GetImage");` you are basically saying: send a GET requets to `Home/GetImage` using Ajax and if the request succeeds update the contents of `#targetDiv` with the result. As your controller action sends binary data, this binary data will be injected into the div.

Comment: +1. The proper way to do it with Ajax would be to set the "src"-attribute of the img-tag to the new value (e.g. getimage?value1=&value2 etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the content type of your response to accommodate the fact you're sending back an image. If you don't your binary stream will be interpreted as text, hence the garbled stuff you get.

There's a related question here: [Can an ASP.NET MVC controller return an Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your code, before you read the file and send it back

```
this.Response.Clear();
this.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
```

on the markup side instead of putting the content into a div you need to put it into an image tag.