# how to retrive binary data from database and display on iamge

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to retrive image from database binaryfile. but i dont know how to display on PrtImg1 img

```
<img id="PrtImg1" alt="Product Image 1"  runat="server" 
                  class="picture"/>


if (sqlDataReader2["ProductColorType"].ToString() == "Type1")
                                    {
                                        Byte[] imgData = (byte[])sqlDataReader2["ProductImg"];
                                        Response.ContentType = (sqlDataReader2["ProductImg"].ToString());
                                        Response.OutputStream.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);
```

Comment: Check these two approaches
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880515/display-image-from-database-in-asp-mvc?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757799/displaying-a-image-from-a-database-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=1

Comment: and another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560830/convert-byte-array-to-image-and-display-in-razor-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

.aspx

```
<img id="PrtImg1" alt="Product Image 1" runat="server" class="picture" />
```

.cs

```
if (sqlDataReader2["ProductColorType"].ToString() == "Type1")
{
    Byte[] imgData = (byte[])sqlDataReader2["ProductImg"];

    string base64String = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);
    }
    catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
    {

    }

    this.PrtImg1.Src = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64String);
}
```