# Faster to generate thumbnail and write to response in Handler or generate in Http module and let IIS handler the rest?

Tags: asp.net, performance, httphandler, thumbnails

What will be faster:

- Generate a thumbnail then write the stream to the Http response using an Http Handler.
- Generate a thumbnail in a http module on one of the earliest events and let IIS handle the rest of the request.

Thanks,
Ash.

Answer (score 0):

Any answer you get here is likely to be an answer to the question "what SHOULD be faster" not "What IS faster".

To determine what ***is*** faster, you should try some performance tests.  Try both methods, and use some app that will call them repeatedly, and see which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in how to return an image from MVC and some perf tests I ran against it, I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image/1349318#1349318) to a question on returning images from MVC. I did not test HTTP modules.

My results were:

- **MVC:** 7.6 milliseconds per photo
- **Static:** 6.7 milliseconds per photo