# Downloading files in ASP.Net MVC web applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project that requires the ability to let a user download a pdf from a static location on the server.  I'm reading the instructions from [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/10/writing-a-custom-file-download-action-result-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx) website, it's an old post and I notice they specify in an update that Microsoft's MVC framework has long since included and Action Result that allows the same functionality they discuss thus rendering it obsolete, I've looked a bit online but haven't been able to find any resources that discuss this built-in functionality.  If anyone has any links or other information that discuss this it would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions, I'll be working to implement a demo based on the information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`FileResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx) instead of `ActionResult` to return file stream in the response. For an example, look at [Can an ASP.Net MVC controller return an Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image) question here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public ActionResult Show(int id) {
        Attachment attachment = attachmentRepository.Get(id);

        return new DocumentResult { BinaryData = attachment.BinaryData,
                                    FileName = attachment.FileName };
    }
```

Which uses this custom class, probably similar to FileResult :

```
 public class DocumentResult : ActionResult {

    public DocumentResult() { }

    public byte[] BinaryData { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileContentType { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
        WriteFile(BinaryData, FileName, FileContentType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Setting the content type is necessary even if it is NULL.  Otherwise, the browser treats the file
    /// as an HTML document.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="content"></param>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    /// <param name="fileContentType"></param>
    private static void WriteFile(byte[] content, string filename, string fileContentType) {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        context.Response.ContentType = fileContentType;
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);

        context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return `FileResult`.