# Using a .NET MVC Controller Action as the Source for an HTML <img>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, controller-action

I'm trying to display the picture associated with a user in my database (the picture field's data type is `image`) on a page - unfortunately the code below fails to do that.

**HTML**

```
<img src="/User/Picture/1" />
```

**Controller Action**

```
public byte[] Picture(int id){
    UserRepository r = new UserRepository();
    return r.Single(id).logo.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Apologies, I didn't read up enough on this!

All that needed to be done was make the Controller Action return `FileContentResult`

```
public FileContentResult Picture(int id)
{
    UserRepository r = new UserRepository();   
    return new FileContentResult(r.Single(id).logo.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image) has a lot of useful answers. You probably need the FileContentResult-related answers.

In short, you need to return appropriate ActionResult, and not just array of bytes.