# retrieve dynamic server data with img src

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently using ajax jquery to populate an img src with a dynamic value. Since the image is going to the server anyway i would like to cut out the jquery portion of the code

What I currently have

Javascript (this is the code i want to trash)

```
var Onload= function () {
    $.each($('.image'), function (x, item) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/MyController/MyAction/?imageName=' + $(item).attr('data-image-name'),
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $(item).attr('src', data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
    });
};
```

Server side code

```
public string MyAction(string imageName)
{
    return imageUrl = _myService.GetImageUrl(imageName);
}
```

HTML

```
@foreach(var i in Model)
{
    <img src="" class="image" data-image-name="@i.Name"/>//this is current html
    //<img src="/MyController/Myaction/imageName" + @i.Name />
    //i am trying to get something like second img tag
    //but if i do this it populates with the controller/action url, 
    //not the result of the action method url
}
```

I know about viewmodels and things of that sort. I am not looking for an answer that says, "put this info into your model/viewmodel."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a .NET MVC Controller Action as the Source for an HTML <img>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045952/using-a-net-mvc-controller-action-as-the-source-for-an-html-img)

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple options:

-Put it in the ViewModel (honestly, the cleanest option in my opinion)

-Do something like this:

```
@foreach(var i in Model)
{       
    <img src="@_myService.GetImageUrl(@i.Name)"/>
}
```

-Create an action that returns the image, not the url. I think that may be closest to what you're looking for:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string imageName)
{
    var path= Server.MapPath(_myService.GetImageUrl(imageName));
    return base.File(path, "image/jpeg");
}

<img src="/MyController/Myaction/?imageName=@i.Name" />
```

Comment: I did the second solution. I get a 500 error. Looking the at the preview tab in network it has following error message: 'myimage.jpeg' is not a valid virtual path. If i copy and past the url in a new browser window it show the image correctly

Comment: the type is text/html. I think that's causing the issue. It should be image/

Comment: Hm, I noticed that I should have used `@i.Name`, and of course `_myService` probably wasn't initially defined, but I assume you took care of that. When you view the source of the page, what is the src that is rendered?

Comment: src="/MyController/MyAction/?imageName=Image1"

Comment: Ah, so maybe `_myService.GetImageUrl(imageName)` is returning `myimage.jpeg` which `Server.MapPath()` doesn't like. You might need to refactor a bit to get the virtual path of the image, not just the image name.

Comment: the method returns the fully qualified url.