# Web: View raw content of a file from the FileName and the FileContent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mime-types

I'm using **ASP MVC**, and I want to allow the user to download/view files from my web server.

The files are not located in this web server.

I know the **file content** (a `byte[]` array), and also the **file name**.

I want same behavior that as the Web Broswer. For example, if the mime type is text, I want to see the text, if it's an image, the same, if it's binary, propose it for a download.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for images is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image)

For other types, you have to determine the MIME type from the file name extension. You can use either the Windows Registry or some well-known hashtable, or also IIS configuration (if running on IIS).

If you plan to use the registry, here is a code that determines the MIME content type for a given extension:

```
    public static string GetRegistryContentType(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

        // determine extension
        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);

        string contentType = null;
        using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                object ct = key.GetValue("Content Type");
                key.Close();
                if (ct != null)
                {
                    contentType = ct as string;
                }
            }
        }
        if (contentType == null)
        {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream"; // default content type
        }
        return contentType;
    }
```

Comment: My web server will be IIS or XSP (mono), so I cannot assume that I can access a Windows Registry :-(

Comment: ohh... you can always go for a fixed list then. There is a list available here as a start: http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was thinking in implement two providers (for linux or windows), but finally I will manage a fixed list (I will take the mime.types file from the apache server)