# Asp.net MVC routes ending with file extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have an action that returns a Dynamically Generated image however I need the call to that action to end with a *something*.jpg.

This answer is very similar to my action [Can an ASP.NET MVC controller return an Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image/5458073#5458073)

MY action takes in a string called ID which I intend to pass the *Something*.jpg but my problem is that while this works locally when I deploy to my server and try it I get an IIS 7 404 error.

It looks like IIS is trying to find the final rather than calling the action, at no point is the action called.

I've tried adding the following to the global.asax to force it to call the action but to no avail.

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
```

Could it be an issue with Mime types?

Comment: @Darin: Are you talking about the `Application Pool` mode?

Comment: @Neil Knight, yes that's what I am talking about.

Comment: @Darin: currently set to classic mode.

Comment: @Morgeh, try going Integrated.

Comment: @Darin: that worked thank you, if you want to drop it in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Morgeh, posted my comment as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to set your IIS 7 Application Pool in Integrated mode.

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem but unfourtunately my app runs under IIS 6. I think is not possible to turn Integrated Mode in IIS 6 right? How can I solve the problem then?? Thanks!!

Comment: @Julen, you will have to setup extensionless urls in IIS 6: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx