# MVC Razor Routing .mp3 files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have following url

```
Call/GetAudio/f9715595-a540-4add-8419-f9cdf906c7ec.mp3
```

Now the problem is the above .mp3 file does not actually exist, rather I want it to go to "CallController", "GetAudio" function which will then return the bytes array as FileResult.

I imagine I need to configure some routing for this in global.asax, is this achievable?

Basically I want all .mp3 files to go through routing.

Comment: just serve the .mp3 file type through your controller. Then you can drop the `.mp3` file extension since the controller will be serving only mp3's. Your routing will be a normal route `{Controller}/{Action}/{id}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All paths will go through routing, regardless of extension.
(assuming IIS is correctly configured to use ASP.Net as a wildcard handler)

Just make a normal route.

Note that there is no reason to include `.mp3` in the URL; just make sure to include an appropriate `Content-Type` in the response, which you should do regardless of URL.

Comment: Yes, I know there's no reason to include .mp3 file (or any extension in url). However, I need this for very specific purpose - I am developing jquery player + jquery mobile for Android, and from what i gather it needs the .mp3 file to force android to download the file, otherwise it thinks that the url is invalid and will not even attempt to download it - thus jquery player cannot play the file since it's not downloaded.

Comment: Like you said, I got IIS error saying "file not found" when trying the url. Is conguring IIS the only way to achieve this?

Comment: IIS should be configured to use ASP.Net for all requests.  If it isn't, you should fix that.

Comment: However, that sounds unlikely.  Android should be reading the `Content-Type`, not the URL extension.

Comment: I have done more testing, and yeah it's nothing to do with the extension - it was actually security thing. Seems like even after the user is logged in, when jplayer tried to download the mp3 file - it either fires different session or somehow thinks that the user is not logged in. Very weird, even though it works perfectly fine on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar answer, only it's serving images instead of audio files, however the principles are the same.
[Can an ASP.NET MVC controller return an Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image)

Simply create a Controller Action that serves MP3's. Then you can drop the .mp3 file extension since the controller will be serving only mp3's. Your routing will be a normal route `{Controller}/{Action}/{id}`

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer my question. The other post wanted url without extension to return image that physically exist - while I need the url with .mp3 extension - to trick android/jquery player per my other comment to SLaks answer.

Comment: SLaks comment is spot on `However, that sounds unlikely. Android should be reading the Content-Type, not the URL extension. `