# Close or block page if user traverses through a web application folder using MVC2

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-mvc-2, directory

I am new with ASP.NET and MVC2 and I am wondering how can I determine if a user has traversed through one of my web application folders. For example, the URL in the address bar is

> localhost:some numbers/Images/Others/model1.jpg

and the page displays the image. Instead of displaying the image, I want to close or block the page (if that is possible).

(Please edit this if necessary if my terminology is wrong.)

Finally, note that I tried `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` and `Request.ServerVariables["URL"]` but neither returns want I want.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if someone CAN access an image, or if someone HAS accessed an image?

Comment: @Tieson If some has accessed the image. From above, user has gone to this URL "localhost:some numbers/Images/Others/model1.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any straight forward method but I've used [handlers/modules](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx) and *loaded* the css/Javascript dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to handle requests to all (or maybe just *.jpg) files including static files?

To handle requests to existing files in the code you need to following:

- runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests in Web.Config to let IIS forward requests to your code instead of serving static content first (i.e. check this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx))

  - configure routing to hadnel requests for existing files `RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = false` and add corresponding IgnoreRoute - http://forums.asp.net/t/1536510.aspx

To server content - return [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.108).aspx) from your handler. Usually done by using File helper method of Controller. See this question: [Can an ASP.NET MVC controller return an Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image)