# Display image in a popup in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, aspose

I am generating a Word document with aspose and I would like to show some kind of preview to the user before they decide to save the document. I have a view where users can enter their info:

```
@model WordAutomation.Models.Document

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Document";
}

<h2>Document</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Document</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientTitle)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientTitle)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientFullName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientFullName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientFullName)
        </div>      

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Preview", "Preview")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Now I have the controller for preview:

```
  public ActionResult Preview()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

When the user clicks on preview I want to generate the Word document (that part is already done) and display it as a popup on the screen for the user.

Exactly what I need is how to display image on the screen, once I'll enter the preview controller. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Do you already have a method for generating an image of the Word document you've created?

Comment: Can you use a modal instead of a popup? Its easier to manipulate the html and css, once its on the same page.

Comment: @Gabriel Whatever it works, I just need something where I can show the image, modal would be excellent. Can you give me some kind of example how can I trigger the modal from the controller please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jquery ui dialog to create a modal and use it something like this. Do not use popup of  Access http://ui.jquery.com to download the library and reference on your application.

At your view, you can add this code to create a dialog modal and load it from the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#previewDocumentDialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Preview',
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 500,
            open: function(event, ui) {
                //Load the PreviewWordDocument action which will return a partial view called _PreviewWordDocument
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("PreviewWordDocument")"); //add parameters if necessary
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        // an event click for you preview link to open the dialog
        $('#previewLink').click(function () {
            $('#previewDocumentDialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Create a Div and your link preview, add an id to create/open an dialog of jquery ui

```
<div id="previewDocumentDialog" title="Preview" style="overflow: hidden;">

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Preview", "Preview", null, new { id = "previewLink" })
</div>
```

On your controller, you need to have a action to return this PartialView

```
public ActionResult PreviewWordDocument(/*add parameters if necessary*/) {  
    var model = "path of your word image";  
    return PartialView("_PreviewWordDocument", model);
}
```

You can type your partialView with the image path on a string

```
@model string

<img src="@model" style="width:400;height:500px;" />
```

And remember to [do not use popup window of browser.](http://uxmovement.com/forms/why-modal-windows-have-killed-popup-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [JQuery Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox) to display the image using [an action which returned the preview image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image) you've created as the href for the image source.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a modal instead of a popup, you can trigger it with javascript, or jquery if you like. [JQuery Modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal) is a good option.

Then you can clone the html of the content that you want display using [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and use a different CSS style for your modal div.