# MelonJS and ASP.NET : enable HTTP GET on Content file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, melonjs

I am triyng to run a little MelonJS Game in a ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor Page. First of all, I think **it is possible to fix this without any MelonJS knowledge** (only MVC 4).

The problem is:

At one moment, MelonJS need to load some files from the server (I put the files in Content/data/[..]/file.ext). To do this it performs for each file a HTTP GET on `localhost:XXXX/%EveryThingIWant/file.ext%.`

Of course, it fails. I try to enable DirectoryBrowsing but it did not solve the problem. In order to get it working quickly, I did this (I'm not proud of it, it's just a quick fix):

I create a new action in one of my controllers:

```
    //
    // GET: /Game/Data

    public FileResult Data(string path)
    {
        string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + path);

        byte[] fileByte = null;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(physicalPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            fileByte = new byte[fs.Length];

            fs.Read(fileByte, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        }

        var result = new FileContentResult(fileByte, "tmx");

        return result;
    }
```

And I set the %EveryThingIWant/file.ext% to  "Game/Data?path=[..]/file.ext".

It works but I am wondering if there is not a better solution to perform that. Put the file in an other folder? I tried to enable DirectoryBrowsing and adding a MIME type but I failed util now. It is possible?

Comment: When you say it fails, what is the error you get?

Comment: You can see examples of some more-concise approaches to this problem in the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image

Comment: @asymptoticFault : if I don't add my dirty solution, as MelonJS performs a HTTP GET on nothing, it return a 404. I am looking th other links, thanks !

Comment: My solution works ! It can be improved (with try/catch, etc), of course, but I am looking for another solution. I wonder there is one with no code but about configuration. For example, enabling DirectoryBrowsing and adding a MIME type but I failed util now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the good way but this is what I've finally done :

-I put the data in a specific folder (I chose App_Data but I don't know if it's the good place for that)

-I put a Web.config in this folder with that content :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".tmx" mimeType="text/plain" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

(I guess I have to specify all custom extension)

-In my case (App_Data folder), I had to add in the global Web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <hiddenSegments>
        <remove segment="App_Data" />
      </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</configuration>
```

With these modifications, the HTTP GET on my resources works well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article on [how to return a file as a response](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/uploading_and_returning_files#how_to_return_a_file_as_response).  It covers the `FileResult` and its subclasses and the inherited `File` methods from the base controller.

Comment: My solution works ! It can be improved (with try/catch, etc), of course, but I am looking for another solution. I wonder there is one with no code but about configuration. For example, enabling DirectoryBrowsing and adding a MIME type but I failed util now.