# Download file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, download

I try to download a file in javascript, passing filename from html

HTML:

```
 <img border="0" src="/Content/Images/Icons/color-16/disk-return-black.png" width="20" height="18" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="downloadDocFoto('@item.CaminhoDocFoto')" id="btnDownloadDocFoto_Contrato">
```

Javascript:

```
function downloadDocFoto(NomeDocFoto) {
    alert(NomeDocFoto);
    var url = '~/App_Data/uploads/' + NomeDocFoto + '';
}
```

the var url have the path where files stay, and the filename

Comment: Remove ~/ from url in javascript function

Comment: Dont solve my prob, and the `var url` is the simple variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can NOT access `App_Data` folder directly! This is made for security reasons.
if you want to get files from it you have to write custom `HttpHandler` or `Controller` with appropriate `Action`

Comment: Ok, i'll change. But who is the javascript code to download file?

Comment: it will point to, for example: /File/Get where File is controller and Get is action that writes file to response. How to do that? Search Google

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image