# Images not rendering in localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have images sitting within my project root at Data\Images\articles. I am trying to render the image using the code below in MVC:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.Image)" alt="Image" />
```

It's not displaying the image, however the rendered html code is correct.

```
<img src="/Data/Images/Articles/16fd7bc5-3bac-474a-a806-b8d72b974960.PNG" alt="Image">
```

I am running the project from Visual studio server, not through IIS. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler or browser's dev tools to check the requested URL?

Comment: Also, make sure its not cache (could try another browser or event private/incognito mode).

Comment: So if you visit `http://localhost:XXXX/Data/Images/Articles/16fd7bc5-3bac-474a-a806-b8d72b974960.PNG`, what do you get?

Comment: browser dev tool shows the correct url, and its definitely not cached

Comment: @DavidG i get HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: So that image doesn't exist in that folder

Comment: There seems to be something wrong in the path. 404 means the file doesn't exist

Comment: @DavidG Image does exist physically.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? It's a long GUID for a name, you may have mistyped.

Comment: yes i am sure. @DavidG

Comment: You could try to access the image by its physical path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image (just for testing purposes)

Comment: What URL do you see in your browser for the page that works?

Comment: guys its sorted now , long file name was causing the problem here. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different file name was generating as compare to what was expecting in logic causing 404 error when validating the image file name