# UrlRewrite not working when using TransferRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis

I have a UrlRewrite rule, which looks like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>             
        <rule name="Add prefix to pictures request" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^pictures/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/pictures/pictures-dev/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The idea is to add some kind of a prefix to original request (in this case, the prefix is **/pictures/pictures-dev/**. Later this rewritten request is processed by a plugin and not handled by my code.
The **/pictures** endpoint is the main endpoint for such requests. The rewrite rule is vital, and without the rule applied the request won't be processed.

Also I have a controller named **ImagesController**, which has a single method **Get**. This method should act like the **/pictures** endpoint, but does some additional processing. The only thing is important that **/images** endpoint cannot issue client-side redirect (**HTTP 301**) by design.

So, it is desired to redirect all requests from **/images** to **/pictures**. Due to additional processing, I cannot simply redirect requests from **/images** to **/pictures**.

To achieve this, I've done the following in the **ImagesController**:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(long id)
{
     // Some work to be done here
     // ....
     // TransferRequest does not return in case of successful request
     HttpContext.Current.Server.TransferRequest($"~/pictures/{id}", true);

     return null;
 }
```

As I've found a lot about **TransferRequest**, this method should re-run the whole IIS request stack, so I suppose UrlRewrite should also be executed.

I expect "pictures/{id}" to be rewritten into "/pictures/pictures-dev/{id}".
However, I see that "/pictures/{id}" issued by **TransferRequest** is not rewritten, which makes me think that UrlRewrite module is not executed against this "transferred" request.

What am I missing?
Or maybe there are other ways to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing the fact that `TransferRequest` and URL rewriting is totally unnecessary in MVC because you can use *routing* to do the same thing (only better). URL rewriting takes a URL and writes it to another URL, which it then passes onto the handler. Routing sends a request *directly* to a handler without any faking of URLs. You need to cut out the middle-man and just use routing. See [Can an ASP.NET MVC controller return an Image?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/186062/181087).

Comment: @NightOwl888 Well, I need to execute some code in **ImagesController.Get** method before redirect. If I hadn't to, I'd definitely use routing options. Also I'm not in control of **/pictures** endpoint because it's handled by a plugin, and it is vital to use this endpoint finally.