# Show image saved on database in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have saved an image in MSSQL server database using the IMAGE format.
It shows as bytes from the database, I want to convert that byte stream to image in HTML and display that.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://debugmode.net/2014/10/07/fetching-image-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/). It shows as Image even though tutorial describes it will display the Image properly it shows Only the "Image" instead of an actual image file.

```
 <td>

        @{ byte[] photo = item.image;
            string imageSrc = null;
            if (photo != null)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                ms.Write(photo, 78, photo.Length - 78);
                string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
            }
        }

        <img src="@imageSrc" alt="Image" />

    </td>
```

Output of the code

[image]

**Rendered Result Source**

[image]
Please help me, I am a beginner to ASP.net

Comment: What is the resulting client-side HTML for this?  Specifically, what is the resulting `src` value?  Is the image a valid JPEG?

Comment: @David I have added the resulting image.

Comment: Ok, and how about the HTML?

Comment: @David I have mentioned the HTML Code in the code block of the question

Comment: Not the resulting HTML in the browser, you haven't.  You've shown code which generates HTML, and you're assuming that it generated what you expect.  Don't assume, debug.  What is the *actual resulting HTML* that gets generated?

Comment: @David Sorry, I have added the rendered HTML code part of screenshot

Comment: Looks like `imageSrc` is empty.  Have you confirmed that `photo` isn't `null`?  It seems that you have some debugging to do as you have some false assumptions somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152078/discussion-between-west-user-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a separate action that returns the image using the File() helper as mentioned here;

[Can an ASP.NET MVC controller return an Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image)

Then setting the src to the Url of that new action. This will be more flexible way to do things