# Show PDF without path in URL

Tags: php, controller

Refer to [Can an ASP.NET MVC controller return an Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image)
, the answer suggest to return image file from controller in C#.

My question is:

Can I do the same thing or similar in PHP? What I want is to hide PDF path from URL.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to hide the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to hide the real local path of your pdf file using php. If this is the case, you can use something like this:

```
<?php

    $localfilename = 'my_local_path/my_file.pdf';

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='download.pdf'");

    readfile($localfilename);

?>
```

I hope this helps you. Greetings!

Comment: Thanks joelperez, this not what I want but it give me the clue to solve my issue.