# Loading Images on HTML Asynchronously using MVC

Tags: html, vb.net, image, model-view-controller, basic

I need to implement a Web Page with a Profile Picture of the user.
Because the loading of the picture from the database takes about 2 seconds to complete, I need to put a GIF with Circle Animation while the Profile Picture is loading.

[image]

Then, once the Database has completely replied back with the image, it should change the GIF image to the User's Profile Picture.

[image]

Here is the controller:

```
  <HttpGet>
        Public Async Function ProfilePicture(ByVal UserId As Integer) As Task(Of ActionResult)
            Using oUser As New User
                oUser.UserID = UserId
                Dim oData As Byte() = Await oUser.RetrievePicFromDb
                If oData IsNot Nothing AndAlso oData.Length > 0 Then
                    Return File(oData, "image/jpg", "")
                Else
                    Return File("~/Content/Images/default-profile.png", "image /jpg", "")
                End If
            End Using
        End Function
```

Here is the data retrieval from the database:

```
Public Async Function RetrievePicFromDb() As Task(Of Byte())
        Dim b As Byte()
        Try
            Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
                cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLServer").ConnectionString
                cn.Open()
                Dim oCmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
                oCmd.Connection = cn
                oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                oCmd.Parameters.Clear()
                oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID)

                oCmd.CommandText = "Select Picture From Users Where UserID = @UserID"
                Dim iCol As Integer = 0
                Dim oReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader
                oReader.Read()
                Dim bImageByte(oReader.GetBytes(iCol, 0, Nothing, 0, Integer.MaxValue) - 1) As Byte
                oReader.GetBytes(iCol, 0, bImageByte, 0, bImageByte.Length)
                Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(bImageByte)
                Using ms
                    Dim jpgMS = New System.IO.MemoryStream
                    Dim jpgImage As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)

                    jpgImage.Save(jpgMS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                    b = jpgMS.ToArray()
                End Using
                oReader.Close()
                cn.Close()
            End Using
            Return b
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

A warning message is being generated:

[image]

and the displayed picture is:

[image]

Any amount of help is appreciated!

Comment: 1. Write an action method that returns the image [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image) 2. Write cshtml that references the image and lazy loads it [link](https://css-tricks.com/the-complete-guide-to-lazy-loading-images/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have edited the post include Source Code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this `await Task.Run(() => @Your synchronous function);`

Comment: Nice! This one nailed it! Thanks Joshua! But for VB, the syntax is Dim oData As Byte() = Await Task.Run(Function() oUser.RetrievePicFromDb)